# Can i approximate the inner product of two vectors by the sum of their coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there any correlation of the inner product between two $n$ dimensional vectors $\vec x ,\vec y$ with non negative coefficients and the summation of their coefficients? Put it more clearly can i approximate the inner product $\vec x \cdot\vec y$ by the sum of their coefficients: $\sum_{i=0}^{i=n-1}({x_i+y_i})$? Or with any another operation which is homomorphic to the inner product

Comment: What happens for $\langle x,x\rangle$ if all the coefficients of $x$ are negative?

Comment: I exclude this case. I assume all the coefficients are positive integers $\in \mathbb{Z}_q$

Comment: What does "homomorphic to the inner product" mean?

Comment: @curious well then you don't have a vector space since no element has an inverse such that $x+(-x)=0_V$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Homomorphic means that if $a*b = a&b$ the operations *,& are homomorphic. Or at least with some error

Comment: Down-voted the question because it is unclear, misguided, and "curious" doesn't take advice.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the standard n-dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$ the inner product is
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i y_i}$? Note that your formula misleadingly works with $n+1$ coefficients.

Comment: Yes this is the inner product but i am questioning if you can approximate this operation with another one.

Comment: The sum is very simple. What kind of approxmiation do you think of? What is the allowed error?

Comment: You don't understand the question i think. If it is very easy write it down please

Comment: Then reformulate it to make it clearer. Take for example $n=10, x_i = 2, y_i=-2, \;$ then the inner product is -40 but your sum is 0. I cannot think of any reasonable approximation for this.

Comment: So the answer to my question is no :).  there is no problem with my question i think :)

Comment: But let's assume there are no negative coefficients. I do only care about positives.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
\sigma(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|+|y_i|
$$
Consider the vectors $x=(1,0)$ and $y(0,1)$: $x\cdot y=0$, yet $\sigma(x,y)=2$.

For the other direction, consider $x=(a,0)$ and $y=(a,0)$: $x\cdot y=a^2$ and $\sigma(x,y)=2a$. As $a\to\infty$, the inner product gets far bigger than the sum of the coefficients.

Thus, there can be no constant so that
$$
|x\cdot y|\le C\sigma(x,y)
$$
or so that
$$
\sigma(x,y)\le C|x\cdot y|
$$
even when the coefficients are non-negative.

Comment: Can it can be approximated with other operation than the sum?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the sum of the coefficients is an unboundedly poor approximation (that is, the error can grow without bound).  Consider $\langle 0, x \rangle$.  Your approximation yields $\sum_i x_i$, whereas a real inner product would yield $0$.

The question we must ask is, to what end are you trying to "approximate" the inner product?  You might want to look up the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: Ok maybe the sum doesn't work. But what is the best approximation that i can make?With what operations?

Comment: @curious can you provide some motivation? For most purposes calculating the normal dot product is not expensive. Sometimes the motivation can help others answer better.

Comment: Compatibility with cryptographic operations

Comment: Compatibility in what sense? What operations? We're gonna need more than that.

Comment: The question is simple. How i can best approximate the inner product other than the classical way with operation that do not involve so many multiplications

Comment: The question is simple yes and the answer is you can't but if you actually provide the motivation we might be able to suggest alternatives. (Perhaps you do not wish to give too much info away which is understandable but then we can't really help)

Comment: I get the feeling anybody bound by an NDA in a cryptographic application would do a better job of asking the question.

Comment: @nomen what is an NDA?